# Mongoid embeds_one form_for path error for new objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, path, nested

### ***Can you have the same model class be a collection resource in one and a singular resource in the other?***

---

### UPDATE !!!

I think its a mongoid issue, as editing existing photos works. Only new throw the path errors

---

### ORM is Mongoid beta 20

---

### routes.db

```
  resources :products do
     resources :photos do
        collection do
           post 'sort'
         end
     end
   end

   resources :companies do
      resource :photo
   end
```

### photos_controller.rb

before_filter find_or_build_photo

```
  def find_or_build_photo
    # these have many photos
    if !params[:story_id].blank? or !params[:product_id].blank?
    @photo = params[:id] ? @parent.photos.find(params[:id]) :     @parent.photos.build(params[:photo])
    end
    # these have one photo
    if !params[:company_id].blank?
    @photo = @parent.photo ? @parent.photo : @parent.build_photo(params[:photo])
    end
  end
```

I get some "undefined method photo_path" etc. errors in the view with the form_for helper.
My Theorie -> because there is only a "photos"-controller and no "photo"-controller. this confuses the path-blackmagic!?

```
Started GET "/companies/4cf6b9c3499dda12e3000003/photo/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Dec 02    17:51:42 +0100 2010
  Processing by PhotosController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"company_id"=>"4cf6b9c3499dda12e3000003"}
mcu_dev['companies'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4cf6b9c3499dda12e3000003')},     {}).limit(-1)
Rendered photos/_form.html.haml (3893.3ms)
Rendered photos/edit.html.haml within layouts/application (3899.1ms)
Completed   in 6730ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `company_photos_path' for #<#    <Class:0x103842e30>:0x1038404a0>):
    1: 
    2: 
    3: = form_for [@parent, @photo], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
    4:   -if @photo.errors.any?
    5:     #errorExplanation
    6:       %h2= "#{pluralize(@photo.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this photo from    being saved:"
  app/views/photos/_form.html.haml:3:in    `_app_views_photos__form_html_haml___1111817113_2176907420_506750'
  app/views/photos/edit.html.haml:3:in  `_app_views_photos_edit_html_haml__1185726823_2176970040_0'
  lib/include/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
```

---

### when i debug it. the instance variables are set:

http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/6892/rubyerror.png

---

Full Source: github.com/banditj/mongoid-carrierwave-uploadify

Comment: Those are nested resources, to address photos individually (with `photo_path(:id)`) you would need a root-level resources route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding the url:

```
<%= form_for [@company, @photo], :url => company_photo_path(@company) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

This ought to give you a form that POSTs to PhotosController#create. You probably want to do a PUT though, since your controller picks up the photo if it exists, in which case you also need to pass in `:html => { :method => :put }`, which should go to PhotosController#update.

Comment: thx man that totally did the trick. i made a secound form-partial just for the create of single resource. not dry but its a mongoid bug. you saved me!!!

Comment: forgot. :method=>:put breaks it . new path error occurs. mongoid isnt very usable yet for rails 3

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

The reason you're getting the `undefined method photo_path` is because you're not using the nested resource that you have defined.

In your `form_for` you should be doing this:

```
<%= form_for [@company, :photo] do |f| %>
```

Where `@company` is a pre-existing company object.

Comment: hi Ryan, thx for your help and time. thats what i did! but it doesnt work. see my updated question.

Comment: @jimmybandit: Please note I've used a SYMBOL in my `form_for` code intentionally, where you've used an INSTANCE VARIABLE. Because it's a singular resource, the reference in the `form_for` MUST be a SYMBOL.

Comment: @ryan-bigg: throws undefined method `model_name' for Symbol:Class, the code works for embeds_many (https://github.com/davesouth/mongoid-carrierwave-uploadify/blob/master/app/views/photos/_form.html.haml) and update for embeds_one relation. but no create.

Answer (score 0):

The `find_or_build_photo` method is getting really smelly.

It feels like you are unnecessarily overloading the Photo model. A product having many photos is different than an avatar for the Company.

Plus Mongoid gets confused by the multiple embedded_in declarations found in Photo.

I would recommend creating a second model called Avatar for singular resource needs such as adding a photo to a Company or Person. Use Photo for multiple entries in Product or Story.

This is a better model of the real-world. It also allows setting different sizes for Avatar vs Photo. Typically I throw away the original and only make one or two small sizes in Avatar. For Photo I keep the original and make four or five different sizes for more flexible presentation in my stories.

Company would then `embeds_one :avatar`. Where Product would `embeds_many :photos`.

This clean separation of purpose should fix the problem with singular vs multiple resources in routes.

For Avatar, Uploadify is unnecessary. Just use a standard file upload form element. It's simple and can be added to the larger Company form.